# Resultado Busca não localizada

Tags: javascript, html, algoritmo-de-busca

Bom dia!

Tenho dois JS, um que emula algo parecido com um banco de dados seguindo o exemplo:

```
var menu;

$(document).ready(function() {


menu = new clsMenu();

var Exemplo01 = menu.addFolder("Exemplo", "Exemplo")    

})
```

E outro que faz o filtro nele:

```
    function letras(texto) {
        var letrasPorString = [];
        var letrasPorIndex = [];
        var i, letra;

        for (i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
            letra = texto.substr(i, 1);
            if (letrasPorString[letra] === undefined) {
                letrasPorString[letra] = 1;
                letrasPorIndex.push(letra);
            } else {
                letrasPorString[letra]++;
            }
        };

        this.porString = letrasPorString;
        this.porIndex = letrasPorIndex;
    }

    function compararLetras(letrasObj1, letrasObj2, corte) {
        var i;
        var qndeCertas = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < letrasObj1.porIndex.length; i++) {
            var letra = letrasObj1.porIndex[i];
            if (letrasObj1.porString[letra] === letrasObj2.porString[letra]) {
                qndeCertas++;
            }
        };

        var percentual = (qndeCertas / letrasObj1.porIndex.length) * 100;
        return percentual >= corte;
    }

    function duplas(texto) {
        var tduplas = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < texto.length - 1; i++) {
            tduplas.push( texto.substr(i, 2) );
        }

        return tduplas;
    };

    function compararDuplas(duplas1, duplas2, corte) {
        var i, j;
        var encontrados = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < duplas1.length; i++) {
            var dupla = duplas1[i];
            var encontrado = false;
            for (j = 0; j < duplas2.length; j++) {
                if (dupla == duplas2[j]) {
                    encontrado = true;
                }
            };

            if (encontrado) { encontrados++ }
        };

        var percentual = (encontrados / duplas1.length) * 100;
        return percentual >= corte
    }

    function compararKeyTag(key, tag, buscaAproximada, corte) {
        if (buscaAproximada === true) {
            var lk, lt, dk, dt;
            lk = new letras(key);
            lt = new letras(tag);
            dk = new duplas(key);
            dt = new duplas(key);

            if (corte === undefined) { corte = 70 }
            if ( compararLetras(lk, lt, corte) && compararDuplas(dk, dt, corte) ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (tag.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function compararKeysTags(keysArr, tagsArr, buscaAproximada, corte) {
        var encontrados = 0;
        $(keysArr).each(function(index, key) {
            var encontrado = false;
            $(tagsArr).each(function(index, tag) {
                if (compararKeyTag( key, tag, buscaAproximada, corte )) {
                    encontrado = true;;
                }
            });

            if (encontrado) {encontrados++};
        });

        if ( encontrados == keysArr.length ) { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Retornando sempre o resultado deste filtro em uma div no arquivo html:

```
            <h1 style="margin-top: -10%;">
                <b>
                    MENU
                </b>
            </h1>

            <form class="search-container example">
                <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Busca" style="color: black">

                <button type="submit" id="search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </form>

            <div id="menu">

            </div>
```

O problema é, peguei esse projeto ja desenvolvido, e a pessoa que criou ele hoje não está mais trabalhando junto a mim, fora eu ainda não ter um conhecimento a ponto de conseguir fazer o que necessito, que é, quando a busca não retornar resultado, ser apresentado uma mensagem tipo "Sua busca não obteve resultado".

Alguém poderia me auxiliar com isso?

Desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual função é chamada quando se clica no botão de pesquisa? É só ir nessa função que é ativa quando se clica no botão pesquisar e fazer com que quando o retorno da pesquisa for nulo, que ele seja ativado um `window.alert("Resultado Busca não localizada");`.